# How does one keep track of the training error of a Neural Network when using Batch Normalization in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I wanted to keep track of my training error as the Neural Network is trained. During testing, it is customary to remove the batch normalization layer. For example:

```
# when test
# is_training determines if Batch-norm is off or on
error = sess.run([opt, loss], feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training=False})
```

however, say that I want to track the training error of a Neural Network as the number of iterations increases. For simplicity assume that the data sets are large enough to train the model and small enough that computing the error on the entire data set is feasible (I know that its possible to use batches to make computations more efficient or moving averages, but that is besides the point of my question). In this case is the correct way to track the training error by turning off the batch normalization as follows:

```
bx, by = X_train, Y_train
train_error = sess.run([opt, loss], feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training=False})
```

i.e. should we use the data that we trained but turn off batch normalization?

Notice that if we are doing training `is_training=True` should invariable be true. i.e. the training step is:

```
bx, by = get_batch(X_train, Y_train)
b_error = sess.run([opt, loss], feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training=True})
```

however what confuses me is if we should report `b_error` or `train_error`. **In other words, when I want to track my training error, should the batch normalization layer be off or on?** Obviously it should be on during training and off when I pass in the test set, but when I want to report the train error during training, should it be off?

---

Notice that its obvious that batch normalization layer should be off when passing the test or cross validation (CV) data

```
bx, by = X_test, Y_test # or X_cv, Y_cv
test_error = sess.run([opt, loss], feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training=False})
```

Answer (score 0):

For reporting you would use the same metric on both your training and test set.

For example, while training you might use [dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropout_(neural_networks)) to increase the robustness of the net. To figure out how well your net performs out-of-sample, however, you would compare the predictions on the training set to the predictions on the test set using all the nodes in the net.

Comment: I hope to say this in the most respectful way but I don't see how your answer addresses my question. My question is weather when the BN layer should be on during testing even if the train set is passed as the data set to evaluate the net. Not sure what you mean by out sample but I already addressed how the test set should be processed.

Comment: @Pinocchio -- I don't think it will make a lot of difference if is_training is set to True or False, once the batch normalization coefficients start to stabilize. The batch normalization is not "turned off" by is_training=False. Rather the coefficients gamma and beta are not updated and prestored values for these coefficients are used. So once these coefficients are stable for the training set is_training won't matter much (assuming large training batches).